# Java - Possible to have more than one data type using ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to have more than one data type within an array list, or even two of the same data type such as:

```
ArrayList<Integer,Integer,Integer> triple = new ArrayList<Integer,Integer,Integer>();
```

I notice this causes an error but I'm just wondering if there is indeed a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  If you defined a class `Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer>`, you could in turn have an `ArrayList<Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer>>`, however.

Is this for some sort of list of 3d points?